# How can I apply styling to active/hover states within ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been at this for a day or so now and just can't figure out what needs to happen.

I am using ng-repeat to generate a tabbed list of links that is displayed in a simple nav bar. This nav bar is related to a workspace. There are many workspaces that have a color assigned to them by the owner, accessed by `{{ workspace.color }}`.

What I would like to do is style the `:hover` and `:active` states of the `<li>` items such that the background color matches the workspace's assigned color.

```
  <ul class="nav  nav-pills nav-justified" 
      style="border:2px solid {{workspace.color}}" >
  <li ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-class="{active:page.uri == uri,'last':$last}" 
    ng-style="{'border-right':'2px solid {{ workspace.color }}'}">
```

Any idea how to accomplish this? I've done a bunch of digging and I can't seem to find anything mentioning setting style for psuedo classes within ng-class or ng-style.

Obviously I have access to the `.active` class, however the background needs to change based on the project being displayed so I can't hardcode a value in a style sheet.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So might each <li> potentially be a different colour?

Comment: can you please setup a plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using transparency actively? Move the ng-style up to the ul element, and then do something like this for css:

```
li {
  background-color: white;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: transparent; /*or inherit if transparent doesn't work well*/
}
```

As I understood it you wanted the item to be the workspace color when you hover and otherwise white (or something else)..?

Alternatively, keep the ng-style on the li element and style using :not

```
li:not(:hover) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: The problem lies in that a workspace's color attribute is stored in the database and can change. I can't just put `.active {background: blue;}` in a css file because that background color must change based on which workspace the navbar is being rendered for.

Comment: @Gaege Rewrote my answer. Hopefully it is more helpful now.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about looking at it from that angle. Setting the navbar background to the workspace color within ng-style then using classic css to style the `<li>` elements and the opacity in their various states worked like a charm.

The added benefit is that this solution allows me to avoid the "how to get semi-opaque background" issue on the hovered `<li>` elements to get a muted version of the workspace color.

Thanks again.